# Exceeded max size limit of 12000000

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, integration, website-integration

I'm doing a rest GET callout to an external open database. But I'm getting max size limit error. I know this error is due to 12 MB Heap Size limit. 
I'm getting the data from "CPSC Recalls Application Program Interface (API)"

I want to know, what should be my approach to handle the error or reduce the size of data returned from the database.

Comment: limit exceptions are uncatchable, so your only option here is to reduce the amount of data coming from this external database. Hard to be more specific than that with the given level of detail, and details of this external database are likely better answered by SO or the database provider themselves.

Comment: I've updated the details from where I'm getting this

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact that this isn't really the right place to be asking about this external provider. I highly encourage you to look through the documentation for "CPSC Recalls".

Comment: @Derek Thanks for quick response